# HTML and Javascript: Make hidden form field visible with an if statment

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Im writing some html and javascript code for my website, what I want is a drop down with two answers, yes and no. When yes is selected I want a hidden form field (and the button next to it) to become visible and useable. My problem is that the code works if I make a visible form hidden but not the other way around (the way i want it).

Here is the code I'm using, the way that I thought it would work. You shouldn't have to worry about anything after function outputname()

```html
<html>

<body>

Are you a Patron? <br>
<select id="patronAnswer">
  <option value="no">No</option>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select> <button name="name" type="button" onclick="patron()" id="patronSubmit">Submit</button> <br>


<form id="form1">
<input name="name" type="text" size ="20" style="display:none" placeholder="Email used for patreon">
<button id="feildButton"type="button" onclick="outputname()"style="display:none">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
function patron() {
  var patronUser = document.getElementById("patronAnswer");
  x=patronUser.options.selectedIndex
  console.log (x)
  if (x === 1) {
    document.getElementById("form1").style.display="block";
  }
}

function outputname()  {
var email=document.getElementById("form1");
y=email.elements["name"].value;
if (y==="testemail1@gmail.com"||
    y==="testemail2@gmail.com"||
    y==="bob"||
    y==="billy"){
   var down1 = confirm("You will be given the most current build");
   if (down1){
     var url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8KkXdbkXf67WlJhQUg0QWJMUFU"
     var a = document.createElement('a'),
    ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
a.href = url;
a.download = url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
ev.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, self, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  false, false, false, false, 0, null);
a.dispatchEvent(ev);
   }
   else if (down1===false) {
     confirm ("download canceled")
   }
}
  else {
  var down2=confirm("You have not earned the level 2 reward, you will be given the public build.");
  if (down2){
    var url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8KkXdbkXf67T3dUQUlOTmhYQXc"
    var a = document.createElement('a'),
   ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
a.href = url;
a.download = url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
ev.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, self, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                 false, false, false, false, 0, null);
a.dispatchEvent(ev);
  }
  else if (down2===false){
    confirm ("download canceled")
  }
  }
  }



</script>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is an example of one that works but not in the way that i want. again shouldn't have to worry about anything after outputname()

```html
<html>

<body>

Are you a Patron? <br>
<select id="patronAnswer">
  <option value="no">No</option>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select> <button name="name" type="button" onclick="patron()" id="patronSubmit">Submit</button> <br>


<form id="form1">
<input name="name" type="text" size ="20" style="display:block" placeholder="Email used for patreon">
<button id="feildButton"type="button" onclick="outputname()"style="display:none">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
function patron() {
  var patronUser = document.getElementById("patronAnswer");
  x=patronUser.options.selectedIndex
  console.log (x)
  if (x === 1) {
    document.getElementById("form1").style.display="none";
  }
}

function outputname()  {
var email=document.getElementById("form1");
y=email.elements["name"].value;
if (y==="testemail1@gmail.com"||
    y==="testemail2@gmail.com"||
    y==="bob"||
    y==="billy"){
   var down1 = confirm("You will be given the most current build");
   if (down1){
     var url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8KkXdbkXf67WlJhQUg0QWJMUFU"
     var a = document.createElement('a'),
    ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
a.href = url;
a.download = url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
ev.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, self, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  false, false, false, false, 0, null);
a.dispatchEvent(ev);
   }
   else if (down1===false) {
     confirm ("download canceled")
   }
}
  else {
  var down2=confirm("You have not earned the level 2 reward, you will be given the public build.");
  if (down2){
    var url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8KkXdbkXf67T3dUQUlOTmhYQXc"
    var a = document.createElement('a'),
   ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
a.href = url;
a.download = url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
ev.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, self, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                 false, false, false, false, 0, null);
a.dispatchEvent(ev);
  }
  else if (down2===false){
    confirm ("download canceled")
  }
  }
  }



</script>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I got it to how I want it! Basicly what you did worked partially for what I wanted, the new issue was that when page loads the form visible so all I did was add an extra line of code that sets the form to hidden when you load the page! This is exactly how I wanted it! Thank you for your help!

Here's what the new code looks like:

```html
<html>

<body>

Are you a Patron? <br>
<select id="patronAnswer">
  <option value="no">No</option>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select> <button name="name" type="button" onclick="patron()" id="patronSubmit">Submit</button> <br>


<form id="form1">
<input name="name" type="text" size ="20" style="display:block" placeholder="Email used for patreon">
<button id="feildButton"type="button" onclick="outputname()"style="display:block">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById("form1").style.visibility="hidden"

function patron() {
  var patronUser = document.getElementById("patronAnswer");
  x=patronUser.options.selectedIndex
  console.log (x)
  if (x === 1) {
    document.getElementById("form1").style.visibility="visible";
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("form1").style.visibility="hidden";
    var down2=confirm("You have not earned the level 2 reward, you will be given the public build.");
    if (down2){
      var url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8KkXdbkXf67T3dUQUlOTmhYQXc"
      var a = document.createElement('a'),
     ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  a.href = url;
  a.download = url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  ev.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, self, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                   false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  a.dispatchEvent(ev);
    }
    else if (down2===false){
      confirm ("download canceled")
    }
    }
  }

function outputname()  {
var email=document.getElementById("form1");
y=email.elements["name"].value;
if (y==="testemail1@gmail.com"||
    y==="testemail2@gmail.com"||
    y==="bob"||
    y==="billy"){
   var down1 = confirm("You will be given the most current build");
   if (down1){
     var url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8KkXdbkXf67WlJhQUg0QWJMUFU"
     var a = document.createElement('a'),
    ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
a.href = url;
a.download = url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
ev.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, self, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  false, false, false, false, 0, null);
a.dispatchEvent(ev);
   }
   else if (down1===false) {
     confirm ("download canceled")
   }
}
  else {
  var down2=confirm("You have not earned the level 2 reward, you will be given the public build.");
  if (down2){
    var url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8KkXdbkXf67T3dUQUlOTmhYQXc"
    var a = document.createElement('a'),
   ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
a.href = url;
a.download = url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
ev.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, self, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                 false, false, false, false, 0, null);
a.dispatchEvent(ev);
  }
  else if (down2===false){
    confirm ("download canceled")
  }
  }
  }



</script>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```